# Elementary divisibility problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are $a=1$ and $b=2$ the only positive coprime integers with $a\neq b$, such that

$$a^{p} + b^{p} \mid (a+b)^{p}$$

for some odd prime $p$ ?

Comment: The formulation of this question makes one wonder whether this is some competition problem. If you want an answer, you should add some background to the question!

Comment: Yes, please explain from the beginning ... and well-form your question !

Answer (score 8):

[Zsigmondy theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZsigmondyTheorem.html) states that for any $p>1$, $a^p+b^p$ has a primitive prime factor, except when $\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$. Such prime does not divide $a+b$. Hence, $a^p+b^p$ cannot divide $(a+b)^p$ unless it's the exceptional case.